# ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'pandas' - when I have pandas already installed

Tags: python, linux, unix

I am trying to run some Python code via a Bash script (launch.sh). It looks like the Bash script starts to run, but then I get the error returned:

> `ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'pandas'

Below you can see that I have Pandas installed - I have version 0.24.1, so I am wondering why I am getting the Module not found error for Pandas when I have it installed?

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Now on your machine [Pandas](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pandas_%28software%29) is installed ...... but for Python 2, I think you want to use [Python 3](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/History_of_Python#Version_3).

You have to type in the terminal:

```
~$ python3 -m pip install pandas
```

If it returns an error then:

https://bootstrap.pypa.io/get-pip.py  <- copy and run this (Python 3)

Or install pip with whatever method you want.